# In a constructor for a WPF Window, what should go before InitializeComponent() and what after?

Tags: wpf, coding-style

In general, I've been initializing the properties of the `Window` itself before `InitializeComponent()` and setting up controls contained within afterwards.  However, I haven't been all that consistent, and I haven't really noticed a problem with the ordering. So:

- Am I (potentially) doing something horrible?  In particular, are there any issues with setting properties of child controls before `InitializeComponent()`?
- What is good style in this regard?

Edit: Since the first two answers I got were a little bit contradictory, let me be more specific:

```
public Foo Foo {get; protected set}
public FooWindow (Foo foo)
{
    Foo = foo;
    this.Closing += FooWindow_Closing;
    Foo.Frobbed += Foo_Frobbed;

    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.Title = Foo.Name() + " Window";

    FooListView.ItemSource = Foo.CalculateList();

    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, FooListView);
}
```

Is this about right?  Should I just be doing MVVM and not have anything in my `Window` constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By calling InitializeComponents after some other code you run the risk of accidentally overwriting properties with things that were set in the XAML or of using an uninitialized object. Usually the code-behind is a higher priority than the XAML so I would leave InitializeComponents (aka, parse and load the XAML) at the top.

Comment: It is important to note that, if using MVVM, the DataContext should be set **before** calling InitializeComponent() or else your ViewModel bindings will not get set properly.  InitializeComponent() calls all of your property binding getters, so if it is called first, your bindings will not get the proper values until NotifyPropertyChanged is called again on each of your properties.  This same principle applies to any other initialization logic that may affect how your xaml gets initialized.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your specific questions:

> Am I (potentially) doing something horrible? In particular, are there any issues with setting properties of child controls before InitializeComponent()?

Chances are that your child controls aren't available to you in code yet until you've called InitializeComponents.  It would generally be bad form to do this.

> What is good style in this regard?

This is going to be a matter of taste, but generally I would recommend that if you're going to take advantage of the separation that XAML affords you then I would take it as far as you can.  If you're doing things that are logically about the UI try to do it in XAML.  This isn't so much an MVVM thing as it is a separation of presentation from logic.  Most of what you have in your sample code can be done declaratively, even if just through ValueConverters.

E.g if Foo was a DependencyProperty then you could also attach it in XAML and add the callbacks as part of the ValueChanged callback.  Again, this isn't MVVM, but it is pretty fundamental to WPF.

For most other things, you actually probably want to wait until OnLoaded is called, rather than doing the work in the constructor.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I'm starting to believe the first part, but isn't there a problem (as mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654490/wpf-bad-practice-to-put-code-directly-after-initializecomponent)) of OnLoaded being called multiple times?

Comment: OnLoaded will get called whenever your control gets loaded, which is an appropriate time to hook events and such.  You'll also want to unhook them in OnUnloaded.  If this is a Window then really you should never see OnLoaded called multiple times but it is something to generally be careful about with Controls (the linked question refers to Pages, which would frequently be loaded/unloaded).

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer.  (Sorry, I can only accept one answer, and the other one came first.)

Answer (score 2):

I usually call anything that does not require the Visual Tree before I call **InitializeComponent()**.

All of my implementations use the MVVM pattern, so I prefer to have my ViewModel instantiated and populated before the UI is loaded to the client.

If you always load **InitializeComponent()** first, you run the risk of creating a bad user experience by showing an unpopulated view that suddenly updates versus one that is populated when it comes into view.

Comment: Is this really a problem?  I mean, the user can't see the control until we call `Window.Show()`, which won't happen until the constructor completely exits.  I suppose it might be more of an issue for a `UserControl`, but even then, the object should be fully built by the time it is assigned.