# (ViewModel)DataContext returning null

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got the following event:

```
private void PlaceToken(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectFourViewModel currentViewModel = (ConnectFourViewModel)DataContext;

    Button button = (Button)sender;

    int currentColumn = Convert.ToInt32(button.Content);

    int currentPlayer = currentViewModel.Board.CurrentPlayer;
    currentViewModel.Board.PlaceToken(currentColumn, currentPlayer);
}
```

After the following set up:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var window = new Window();
    var grid = new Grid {};
    ConnectFourViewModel ViewModel = new ConnectFourViewModel();

    //Set up rows and cols
    for(int i = 1; i<=7; i++)
    {
        var col = new ColumnDefinition();
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        var row = new RowDefinition();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    }

    //Set up tiles
    foreach (var item in ViewModel.Board.AllTiles)
    {
        int index = ViewModel.Board.AllTiles.IndexOf(item);

        string name =
              "Col" +
              Convert.ToString(item.Column) +
              "_Row" +
              Convert.ToString(item.Row);

        Label currentTile = new Label{ Name = name};
        Grid.SetRow(currentTile, item.Row - 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(currentTile, item.Column -1);

        //Bind
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = ViewModel.Board.AllTiles[index];
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Contents");

        currentTile.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);

        //Add
        grid.Children.Add(currentTile);
    }

    //Set up Buttons
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        Button currentButton = new Button { };

        //binding
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = ViewModel.CurrentColumn;

        currentButton.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);

        //Set Column names, this has to be after the binding has been set.
        currentButton.Content = i;
        //events
        currentButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PlaceToken);

        //add
        Grid.SetColumn(currentButton, i - 1);
        Grid.SetRow(currentButton, 7);
        grid.Children.Add(currentButton);
    }

    window.Content = grid;
    window.DataContext = ViewModel;
    window.Show();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I'm expecting the line ConnectFourViewModel currentViewModel = (ConnectFourViewModel)DataContext; to set currentViewModel to reflect the information my UI is running off. Unfortunately it's returning null and I'm not sure why.

This is clearly highlighting a gap in my understanding of the topic, but unsure on how to tackle it I could use a hand.
Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: If you have your ViewModel instantiated in your class, why cast it from DataContext? You can just use the instance..

Comment: Also take a look at [In a constructor for a WPF Window, what should go before InitializeComponent() and what after?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11479318/33499)

Comment: That code is abominable, 90% of that should be in XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't assigned the `DataContext` to `ViewModel` anywhere. Assuming you want the `ViewModel`  to be the ViewModel of MainWindow, I suggest you assigne it before `Initialize Component` as shown below. Since it's never assigned you are getting null.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ConnectFourViewModel ViewModel = new ConnectFourViewModel();
    . . .
    . . .
    DataContext = ViewModel ;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a nice concise answer. As a follow up question: You can see where I've set window.DataContext, thinking that because my interface is really in window that the DataContext should work in that separate window. Why do I set the context for main window when everything in represented in window?

Comment: Couldn't wrap my head around your question. I assume you are asking for feedback on the quality?! There are lot of things wrong in the approach you have taken. You are writing code like Winform without using XAML. 2. You dont need another window object for what you are doing! You can add all these controls in the main window and assign it with the view model.